# erros with making a list in Android?

Tags: android, list, int

i am trying to do something simple, make a list to store some integer values

```
public List<int> myList = new List<int>();
```

this is my attempt at makeing the list 
and this is my error message:

Syntax error on token "int", Dimensions expected after this token

so how do you make a list in android?

Comment: int is a primitive type, which cannot be used as a generic. use Integer.

Comment: gives this error when using integer : Cannot instantiate the type List<R.integer>

Comment: your import is wrong. Integer is spelled with a capital I. R.integer is specific to android and is not related to int primitive.

Comment: also, read List doc, it is an interface, you need to instanciate an implementation of it (ArrayList is a common example)

Comment: @njzk2 why you haven't posted above comments as answer

Comment: good question. mostly because i don't have the patience to properly format the answer, i guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List` is an interface, So you cannot instantiate. you must use `ArrayList`

```
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

And `List` is an Interface so you cant create an instance of it instead use `ArrayList`.

> gives this error when using integer : Cannot instantiate the type
>   List

Make sure that you are importing `java.lang.Integer`